# Apache HttpClient 4.x Resume Upload

Tags: java, http, post, put, apache-httpclient-4.x

Is there a standard way to implement a resumable file uploading with Apache HttpClient 4.x?
I tried to override the *writeTo* method in the *FileBody*

```
@Override
public void writeTo(final OutputStream out) throws IOException {
     if (out == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Output stream may not be null");
     }

     BufferedInputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(this.file));

     if(pos > 0){
        stream.skip(pos);
     }
```

Just now occurred to me that probably I need to override *getContentLength* method

```
public long getContentLength() {
    return this.file.length() - pos;
}
```

Or, maybe I could do like this:

```
BufferedInputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
if(pos > 0){
   stream.skip(pos);
}
new InputStreamEntity(stream , file.getSize()-pos);
```

Does anyone have suggestions?